# Котёнок(,) по имени Гав

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

`Однажды жил-был котёнок(,) по имени Гавчонок(,) и у него не было друзей.`

А здесь?

`Однажды жил-был один котёнок(,) по имени Гавчонок(,) и у него не было друзей.`

А здесь?

`Я на улице какого-то котёнка(,) по имени Гав(,) повстречал-таки.`

Comment: Режет слух. "Однажды" — про короткое действие: *Однажды котёнок пошёл гулять.*

Comment: *Я на улице **какого-то** котёнка повстречал.* Очень режет слух, просто жесть. Это как: *Я на улице какого-то человека встретил.*

Comment: *повстречал-таки* — смысл: *вряд ли можно было встретить (этого котёнка), но всё-таки удалось*. Эта частица несёт смысл, она не для красоты.

Comment: Здесь очень хорошо сделать рифму за счёт обособления. Вроде бы вы это хотели (судя по имени).

Comment: "Какой-то" употребляется, когда не знают, какой именно: *Я на улице какого-то зверька видел, но не понял, кто это.*

Comment: "Какого-то" — это буквально "не знаю какого". *— Какой он? — Не знаю. Какой-то...*

Answer (score 2):

(1) *Однажды жил-был котёнок / **по имени ГавчОнок**, // и у него не было друзЕй.*

Вступление к теме, дается **полная** информация. Сравнить: *Жил-был котенок Гав, и у него не было друзей.*

(2) *Однажды жил-был **один** котёнок **по имени Гавчонок**, и у него не было друзей.*

Ситуация та же: Жил был **некий** котенок...

(3) *Я на улице **какого-то** котёнка, **по имени Гав**, повстречал-таки.*

**Пояснительная** информация. *Я видел какого-то котенка, его называли Гав.*

Возможно и другое **толкование:**

*Я на улице **какого-то** котёнка **по имени Гав** повстречал-таки.*

Вам котенок Гав нужен? Я видел какого-то котенка, его зали Гав, но не знаю, этого ли котенка вы ищете.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148831/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Здесь рифма прямо просится, а вы обособляете. Любитель поэзии, называется... Имя явно для рифмы придумано.

Comment: Если что-то известно (имя), то уже не "какого-то", а "одного".

Comment: А зачем опять слеши? Сначала 1, потом 2. По какому правилу они стоят?

Answer (score -1):

Однажды жил-был (один) котёнок , или ничего не нужно

По имени Гавчонок(присоединение) . или , или ... или тире, в зависимости от интонации

И у него не было друзей.

Рифма диктует деление на строфы.

Я на улице какого-то котёнка по имени Гав повстречал таки.

Можно закавычить "котёнка по имени Гав", но не обязательно.

Comment: Жил-был котенок, звали Гавчонок, здесь запятые – желательны. Жил-был котенок по имени Гавчонок,  а здесь вот – не обязательны.

Comment: Наверное так, завали Гавчонок - это уже какое-то придаточное, а не присоединение - которого звали Гавчонок люди.